# Cobrand Password for integrating yodlee FastLink 3.0

Tags: integration, yodlee

We are trying to integrate Yodlee FastLink 3.0 for account verification with our App. We are using Api version 1.1 and have access to Launch Environment. In this launch Environment we are using Key-based Authentication. You can see the launch environment [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayckH.png).
I am trying to follow FastLink 3.0 integrations instructions from [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API/FastLink/FastLink_3.0_Integration_Guide) . In Step 1: **Cobrand Login** we have to send a POST request on **/cobrand/login** endpoint which requires the body as shown below

```
{
    "cobrand":{
        "cobrandLogin":"exampleCobrand",
        "cobrandPassword":"examplePassword"
    }
}
```

taken from API dashboard where as in my dashboard there is no such thing as password, only CobrandId is given as shown in the picture above. Also when you look at API reference page for [this](https://developer.yodlee.com/api-reference#!/cobrand/authenticateCoBrand) POST request, it is mentioned that

*this endpoint is deprecated for customers using the API Key-based authentication and is applicable only to customers who use the SAML-based authentication.*

Is there any other documentation for FastLink 3.0 I missed ? or Am I doing something wrong ? I am stuck here for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have already got a solution for this, but you are/were referring to an outdated documentation. You can see the latest documentation for FastLink 3.0 integration [here.](https://developer.yodlee.com/docs/fastlink/3.0/getting-started)